# How to insert data into table that contain foreing keys using php?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I am still learnig using php, and I got some problems.
So, I have a database named dbcoma and these tables;
[pic of tables and the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtoRN.png)

**here is my question** if I wanna make a registration for patient using php, what is the correct script?

I tried this one but it wasn't working (cant execute)

```
public function createPasien($id_alat, $id_patient, $passwordpas, $namepas, $age, $datein, $id_hospital, $id_alat){
    $password = md5($passwordpas);
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `dbcoma`.`patient` (`id_patient`, `passwordpas`, `namepas`, `age`, `datein`, `id_alat`, `id_hospital`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $id_patient, $passwordpas, $namepas, $age, $datein, $id_alat, $id_hospital);
    $stmt->execute();
    // …
}
```

**UPDATE: I FIXED IT AND FOUND THE PROBLEM. THANK YOU**

Comment: So, did it showed any error?

Comment: @Swellar I tried using this:
`if($stmt->execute()){
    return 1;
   }else{
    return 2;}`

return 1 = data saved.
retunn 2 = some error occured.

when I try it on Postman, it didnt show any error but the preview showed me the message with return 2. "Some error occured"

Answer (score 0):

There are some points to keep in mind:

1. Check the response return by `execute()` statement.
2. Echo the query and run it on the mysql terminal and see what happens.
3. While dealing with `foreign key` the value you are trying to insert must present in the master table, only then you can insert it in child table.

Comment: Hello, thankyou for that points. I found it. and my script already worked. Thank you!